# django import client

Tags: django

i am trying to import the client in django for testing. but when i do, i get this wierd error:

ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

```
from django.utils import unittest
from django.utils import simplejson as json
from django.test.client import Client
```

this is how i imported the client so that i could use it for testing. can someone explain this to me please.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/username/www/site_folder')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'


from django.utils import unittest
from django.utils import simplejson as json
from django.test.client import Client
```

But replace `project` with folder name, where your `settings.py` is

Comment: add this to where i am importing the client or in my settings.py

Comment: i get this when i do that:

"ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named mysite.settings"

Answer (score 4):

The Client is looking for the `settings.py`. You could simply load the client by typing this in your project folder:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Comment: i am sorry but i dont understand. typing that in brings me to a python terminal. how does this load the client?

Comment: this shell is the client - just import your models and do your stuff like `MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)`

Comment: ok i get it, but is there a way for me to import it into the test file like they did here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/

Comment: then you should check @imkost post above

Answer (score 0):

In Pycharm which I use, after following this [Running Django tests in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399046/running-django-tests-in-pycharm)
my problem was solved.

It's in the file > settings > Django Support, and then select the right settings.